# Carrying out this integral

Tags: definite-integrals

I am struggling to reproduce the following result. Given-

$$I_1 = \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty \int_{y'=-\infty}^\infty\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \int_{x'=-\infty}^\infty dy dy' dx dx' \frac{n(x) n(x')}{[(x-x')^2 + (y - y')^2]^{3/2}}$$ and

$$I_2 = \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty \int_{y'=-\infty}^\infty\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \int_{x'=-\infty}^\infty dy dy' dx dx' \frac{1}{[(x-x')^2 + (y - y')^2]^{3/2}},$$

where
$n(x) = 1, -\infty < x \leq 0$ and $n(x) = -1$ for $0 \leq x < \infty$ I need to show-
$$I_1 - I_2 = -4\int_{y=-\infty}^\infty \int_{y'=-\infty}^\infty\int_{x=-\infty}^0\int_{x'=0}^\infty dy dy' dx dx' \frac{1}{[(x-x')^2 + (y - y')^2]^{3/2}}.$$

I tried expressing $I_1$ as

$$I_1 = \int_{x=-\infty}^0\int_{x'=-\infty}^0 (+A) + \int_{x=-\infty}^0\int_{x'=0}^\infty (-A)+\int_{x=0}^\infty\int_{x'=-\infty}^0 (-A)+\int_{x=0}^\infty \int_{x'=0}^\infty (+A)=2\biggl[\int_{x=-\infty}^0\int_{x'=-\infty}^0 (+A) + \int_{x=-\infty}^0\int_{x'=0}^\infty (-A)\biggr]
$$ and $I_2$ as
$$
I_2 =4\int_{x=-\infty}^0\int_{x'=-\infty}^0 (+A),$$ where I absorbed the integrals over y and y' using the factor A, which can be calculated later. However, it does not look like I'm getting the correct result. It would be great if someone could help.

Comment: I've not heard of integrals being carried out beore, What was wrong with it?

Comment: It seems to me these integrals all diverge. Are you sure you transcribed the problem correctly?